# How To pair Rock Candy Mouse with Rock Candy Keyboard receiver (And Vice versa)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

SO I bought myself a rock candy keyboard and mouse. No the box it says "Mouse sharable USB receiver"  Unfortunately it does not share how to pair them together. Wondering how to? I will answer my own question.

Link for keyboard and mouse:

[Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014JCWHNC)

[Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011B2HWEW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pairing the Mouse:
The mouse USB receiver is already paired with the mouse at the factory. However, if you have a replacement USB receiver, you will need to pair it with your mouse. To pair the mouse using the USB receiver, please follow these steps:
1) Ensure that the USB receiver is unplugged.
2) Press and hold the left, right, and middle button (the scroll wheel) at the same time for five seconds.
3) While holding the left, right, and middle buttons; immediately reconnect the USB receiver to your computer.
4) Continue to hold all three buttons for another five seconds, then release.
5) Your Rock Candy Wireless Mouse is now paired with the USB receiver.

Pairing the Keyboard
The keyboard USB receiver is already paired with the keyboard at the factory. However, if
you have a replacement USB receiver, you will need to pair it with your keyboard. To pair the
keyboard using the USB receiver, please follow these steps:
1) Ensure that the USB receiver is unplugged.
2) Press and hold the “Esc” key, then press the “=” key. The LED for Low Battery will
temporarily light up solid to indicate pairing mode.
3) Plug the USB receiver into a USB port on your computer.
```

Comment: How do I remove an item from the pair IE, if it was a receiver for the keyboard and I added the mouse, how do I remove the mouse? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To pair them both you have to unplug the mouse usb receiver, then the keyboard receiver, then on the mouse hold in turn left button then right button then middle button and keep holding all 3 until the mouse led lights up on top, while the led is lit up insert the keyboard usb reciever and the mouse will pair to it and thats it both on the same dongle :)